# Memory Limit error in wordpress front end when resizing

Tags: wordpress, memory, limit, image-resizing

I am new to stackoverflow so please have mercy if I might miss some info.

I have a strange problem using wordpress latest version and plug ins resizing images on upload. It doesnt matter what plug in I use, I get a fatal error because of Memory limit with pictures >2MB. Limit is set to maximum by my provider. Upload from back end works fine, front end form uploads dont work.

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you copy paste the exact error it gives?

Answer (score 1):

Just Adding `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');` in your ‘wp-config.php’ file would increase your PHP Memory Limit to 64 MB or you can add the size as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, that was the first thing I did. And it works in Back end but not in front end. There must be any other conflict I cannot see.

Comment: Just check out this link you will get a clear idea about increasing the upload files size http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-increase-the-maximum-file-upload-size-in-wordpress/.